# PHP MySQL setting variable and getting a select at once

Tags: php, mysql

Im defining a variable inside my query which is  modified and used inside a select after

```
SET @myvar=0;   
SELECT (@myvar:=@myvar+1) AS number ,username FROM mytable;
```

but when i try the query function inside php it doesn't run  because its not a single command,how can i execute it ?

Comment: Just run two separate queries?

Comment: What driver are you using? Why not just store the variable in PHP?

Comment: well as im using a temporary variable and im initializing it ,is it possible to do so?would it be available in the scound query?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing so it is hard to say. Just increasing a variable by 1 can be done in PHP or SQL though. Can you show the driver you are using and what the end goal is?

Comment: @ chris85 because im using the variable in a complicated situation which it has to be inside the query this code is just a simplified example to show my problem

Comment: If you do one query that sets the variable, you can use it in a secondary query after that. Without seeing what you're actually trying to do though, it's correct as chris said - you can probably just do it in PHP.

Comment: im using a trick to simulate the split function (explode in php)inside MySQL and my code in mysql console works correctly but when querying it inside php this happends

Comment: The question about how to run two queries in a single PHP function call cannot be answered unless you specify how do you run the MySQL queries in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite these two queries.

```
SET @myvar = 0;   

SELECT
    (@myvar := @myvar + 1) AS number, username
FROM 
    mytable;
```

into one query

```
SELECT
    (@myvar := @myvar + 1) AS number, username
FROM 
    mytable
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @myvar := 0) AS init_user_param
```